# How is codahale metrics Meter mark() method threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, dropwizard, metrics, codahale-metrics

I have recently begun to learn CodaHale/DropWizard metrics library. I cannot understand how is the Meter class thread-safe (it is according to the documentation), especially mark() and tickIfNecessary() methods here:

https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/3.2-development/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/Meter.java#L54-L77

```
public void mark(long n) {
    tickIfNecessary();
    count.add(n);
    m1Rate.update(n);
    m5Rate.update(n);
    m15Rate.update(n);
}

private void tickIfNecessary() {
    final long oldTick = lastTick.get();
    final long newTick = clock.getTick();
    final long age = newTick - oldTick;
    if (age > TICK_INTERVAL) {
        final long newIntervalStartTick = newTick - age % TICK_INTERVAL;
        if (lastTick.compareAndSet(oldTick, newIntervalStartTick)) {
            final long requiredTicks = age / TICK_INTERVAL;
            for (long i = 0; i < requiredTicks; i++) {
                m1Rate.tick();
                m5Rate.tick();
                m15Rate.tick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that there is a lastTick of type AtomicLong, but still there can be a situation that m1-m15 rates are ticking a little bit longer so another thread can invoke those ticks as well as a part of next TICK_INTERVAL. Wouldn't that be a race condition since tick() method of Rates is not synchronized at all? https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/3.2-development/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/EWMA.java#L86-L95

```
public void tick() {
    final long count = uncounted.sumThenReset();
    final double instantRate = count / interval;
    if (initialized) {
        rate += (alpha * (instantRate - rate));
    } else {
        rate = instantRate;
        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Marian

Answer (score 2):

It is thread safe because this line from `tickIfNecessary()` returns true only once per `newIntervalStartTick`

```
if (lastTick.compareAndSet(oldTick, newIntervalStartTick))
```

What happens if two threads enter `tickIfNecessary()` at almost the same time?

Both threads read the same value from `oldTick`, decide that at least `TICK_INTERVAL` nanoseconds have passed and calculate a `newIntervalStartTick`.

Now both threads try to do `lastTick.compareAndSet(oldTick, newIntervalStartTick)`. As the name `compareAndSet` implies, this method compares to current value of `lastTick` to `oldTick` and only if the value is equal to `oldTick` it gets atomically replaced with `newIntervalStartTick` and returns true.

Since this is an atomic instruction (at the hardware level!), only one thread can succeed. When the other thread executes this method it will already see `newIntervalStartTick` as the current value of `lastTick`. Since this value no longer matches `oldTick` the update fails and the method returns false and therefore this thread does not call `m1Rate.tick()` to `m15Rate.tick()`.

The `EWMA.update(n)` method uses a `java.util.concurrent.atomic.LongAdder` to accumulate the event counts that gives similar thread safety guarantees.

Comment: OK and what if for some reason the thread will hang/wait in the if part after compareAndSet and then another tick will occur. And another thread will also enter the if part after compareAndSet. I mean it is unlikely but possible. Right?

Comment: Can you answer my comment ^^, please? Thanks.

Comment: It can happen, but it is **very** unlikely, since ticks occur every five seconds.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are right. If `tickIfNecessary()` is called such that `age > TICK_INTERVAL` while another call is still running, it is possible that `m1Rate.tick()` and the other `tick()` methods are called at the same time from multiple threads. So it boils down to wether `tick()` and its called routines/operations are safe.

Let's dissect `tick()`:

```
public void tick() {
    final long count = uncounted.sumThenReset();
    final double instantRate = count / interval;
    if (initialized) {
        rate += (alpha * (instantRate - rate));
    } else {
        rate = instantRate;
        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

`alpha` and `interval` are set only on instance initialization and marked **final** those thread-safe since read-only. `count` and `instantRate` are local and those not visible to other threads anyway. `rate` and `initialized` are marked **volatile** and those writes should always be visible for following reads.

If I'm not wrong, pretty much from the first read of `initialized` to the last write on either `initialized` or `rate` this is open for races but some are without effect like when 2 threads race for the switch of `initialized` to `true`.

It seems the majority of effective races can happen in `rate += (alpha * (instantRate - rate));` especially dropped or mixed calculations like:

1. Assumed: `initialized` is `true`
2. Thread1: calculates `count`, `instantRate`, checks `initialized`, does the first read of `rate` which we call `previous_rate` and for whatever reason stalls
3. Thread2: calculates `count`, `instantRate`, checks `initialized`, and calculates `rate += (alpha * (instantRate - rate));`
4. Thread1: continues its operation and calculates `rate += (alpha * (instantRate - previous_rate));`

A drop would occur if the reads and writes somehow get ordered such that `rate` is read on all threads and then written on all threads, effectively dropping one or more calculations.

But the probability for such races, meaning that both `age > TICK_INTERVAL` matches such that 2 Threads run into the same `tick()` method and especially the `rate += (alpha * (instantRate - rate))` may be extremely low and depending on the values not noticeable.

The `mark()` method seems to be thread-safe as long as the [`LongAdderProxy`](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/d87d30ef42c71cf78ff5c3ecb3c5149c55562766/metrics-core/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/LongAdderProxy.java#L22) uses a thread-safe Data-structure for `update`/`add` and for the `tick()` method in `sumThenReset`.

I think the only ones who can answer the Questions left open - wether the races are without noticeable effect or otherwise mitigated - are the project authors or people who have in depth knowledge of these parts of the project and the values calculated.

Comment: Thanks so far, I will leave it open though, so somebody from authors may notice this.